# How to properly implement logout functionality in flutter app?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to implement logout functionality in my flutter app. There is a button in my side menu drawer logout and when the user presses the button I want the user to navigate to login screen and pop all other screens.

I have tried to do it and my code is

```
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
await prefs.remove('userPreference');
await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));

Navigator.of(context)
    .popUntil(ModalRoute.withName(Navigator.defaultRouteName));

Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
     MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (BuildContext context) => 
                LoginScreen(),
     )
);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of using `PushReplacement`, use [`pushAndRemoveUntil`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NavigatorState/pushAndRemoveUntil.html). This pushes your new route, and removes routes routes from the navigation stack until the function passed in returns `true`. If you want to remove all other screens, then pass in a function that always returns false:

```dart
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
await prefs.remove('userPreference');
await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));

Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
  // the new route
  MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (BuildContext context) => LoginScreen(),
  ),

  // this function should return true when we're done removing routes
  // but because we want to remove all other screens, we make it
  // always return false
  (Route route) => false,
);
```